# Is it possible to easily convert a PDF generated from Solidworks back to a 3d model?

Tags: software

I have a PDF of a 3d model that when I view the document properties in chrome I see it was generated with Solidworks PDF publisher (see attached picture). I could go through the work of manually rebuilding the model, but I don't want to if I don't have to, also I don't know how to use 3d modelling software very well, so there's probably a pretty big learning curve.

Is it likely that the pdf contains the metadata necessary to be imported back into a 3d modelling program of any kind? If so, which program and where would I start with that?

[image]

Comment: I really don't think this would be possible. The PDF would be a 2D representation of the 3D object, i.e. a photo of a statue as opposed to the statue itself.